# Firebird SQL group by

Tags: sql, interbase

I want to group by the column `factd_poste_fact` but I get this error:

> SQL error code = -104.
>   Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause).

Code:

```
select
   f.fact_n,
   poste_facture ,
   sum_montant_ttc
from 
   factures f
left outer join
   (select
       facture_detail.fact_n,
       (facture_detail.factd_poste_fact) as poste_facture,
       sum(facture_detail.factd_montant_ttc) as sum_montant_ttc
    from 
       facture_detail
    group by    
       (fact_d.fact_n,facture_detail.factd_poste_fact)
group by
    f.fact_n, poste_facture, sum_montant_ttc
```

Comment: you can't select columns in addition to the aggregate functions if you don't also list those columns in the group by clause. In the subselect here you list fact_n but you don't group on that.

Comment: Why GROUP BY in the main/outer query? (There are no aggregate functions there.)

Comment: You sub-query is invalid, you have to decide what to do with facture_detail.fact_n, either aggregate function or list in GROUP BY.

Comment: sory copie past thenx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to include facture_detail.fact_n in the group by in the sub query

```
SELECT f.fact_n, poste_facture, sum_montant_ttc
FROM factures f
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT fact_n, (factd_poste_fact) AS poste_facture, SUM(factd_montant_ttc) AS sum_montant_ttc
                 FROM facture_detail
                 GROUP BY factd_poste_fact, fact_n
                ) fact_d ON (f.fact_n = fact_d.fact_n)

GROUP BY f.fact_n, poste_facture, sum_montant_ttc
```

Comment: GROUP BY (facture_detail.fact_n,facture_detail.factd_poste_fact )        SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 13, column 40.
,.

Comment: What happens if you remove the parenthesis from the GROUP BY clause?

Comment: thank you very much it works after emove the parenthesis